# Nuget package creation - Class library that targets .NET framework 4.6.1 can not target correct framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I created a class library that targets .net framework 4.6.1 (so pretty much a blank canvas, with a single method to return a string, just for testing purposes). I want to make this into a nuget package. I'm following this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio-net-framework , but when I get to "nuget pack" I get the following warning:

```
"WARNING: NU5128: Some target frameworks declared in the dependencies group of the nuspec and the lib/ref folder do not have exact matches in the other location. Consult the list of actions below:
- Add a dependency group for .NETFramework4.6.1 to the nuspec"
```

I tried adding the dependency group to the .nuspec file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>Author</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>H</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
    <tags>blah</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.6.1" />
    </dependencies>   
  </metadata> 
</package>
```

and I also tried:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>Author</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>H</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
    <tags>blah</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net461" />
    </dependencies>   
  </metadata> 
</package>
```

I still get same error.

I tried using older versions of nuget, where the warning message isn't shown, but the same problem persists (If I try to add via the package manager, it says it has no dependencies).

Comment: Open the generated package as ZIP and then check the folder structure in it. Edit your question to include that please.

Comment: Will your project have nuget dependencies, and if so, is it necessary for it to use packages.config?  If the answer is no or "i don't know", try instead [following the instructions to create a `.NET Standard` package](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli). If you need to target netfx, then right click the project in solution explorer, select edit project file and change the `TargetFramework` element to use `net461` instead of `netstandard2.0`. Pack that (with VS or dotnet.exe) and see if you have the same issue

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue? Apart from nuget pack, you could also consider using [`msbuild /t:pack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-msbuild#add-the-nugetbuildtaskspack-package) command. I assume you're in a .net framework project with packagereference, then you can check if `msbuild command` can meet your needs. May it makes some help :-)

Answer (score 13):

> WARNING: NU5128: Some target frameworks declared in the dependencies
>   group of the nuspec and the lib/ref folder do not have exact matches
>   in the other location. Consult the list of actions below.

This is an open issue in `Github/Nuget`, see [#8713](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8713). I can reproduce same issue in my VS2017 with Nuget V5.3, and this issue goes away if I use Nuget V5.2 or earlier. For this situation, I'm afraid you have to use earlier versions of `Nuget.exe` until the team releases the fix.

> If I try to add via the package manager, it says it has no
>   dependencies

1.If it displays `no package dependencies` though your package project depends on some nuget packages, please check if you're using `packageReference` to manage nuget in your current project. For now, `nuget pack` command doesn't work well for [.net framework projects with packageReference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822826/nuget-package-shows-no-dependencies) or [new SDK format projects](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7352).

You can check details from [Leo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51834778/10910450) to resolve this issue.

2.If the `no dependencies` you mean is that when one project consumes your package, it  doesn't display which framework your project targets like this:

[image]  (We can see your package depends on Newtonsoft.Json but we can't find which framework it targets(net461).)

For this, we need to use command like `nuget pack xx.nuspec` to add the `dependencies+group` into package when packing. Then we can see both targets framework and dependent packages like this:

[image]

Hope all above helps and if I misunderstand anything, feel free to correct me :)

Comment: I can confirm this is still an issue in Nuget v5.4; and GitHub issue #8713 is still open; and downgrading to v5.2 still seems to be the mandatory fix (which worked for me) :(

Comment: Hi there, I also noticed this behavior. And I also tried to use the pack command with the nuspec-file. But if I do so my whole Project-Folder get's packed into the package, including the .cs-Files, bin-Folder, obj-Folder and so on... If I only use the pack command without spec-File it gets packed nicely, but the spec-File is missing the Framework-Group I defined in it. Am I missing something? I've read something about the "convention-based working directory". But I'd like to keep the VS Default Structure. Isn't it possible to use the nuspec-File and pack the package the way like you didn't?

Comment: Still a problem with 5.11. I downgraded to 5.2 and this resolved my problem - cheers!

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Solved my issue with downgrading to nuget.exe version 5.2