# Azure custom Nuget package external libraries

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

- I created a project that is automatically packed into a NuGet package and added to Azure Artifacts through a pipeline
- My NuGet package uses a library from nuget.org called "TextFieldParserStandard"
- I install my NuGet by adding the Artifacts Feed package source in Visual Studio
- I import classes and use functions, but I receive the error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
HResult=0x80070002
Message=Could not load file or assembly 'TextFieldParserStandard, Version=1.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

If I manually search and add this library in my projects where I use the NuGet, my NuGet works. But they should come automatically. When I install other packages I don't need to manually install their libraries.
So the problem is "TextFieldParserStandard" is not installed automatically at once with my NuGet installation.

In Artifacts Feed, I have only my package "MyNuGet version 1.0.0.11538". I don't know if I should have "TextFieldParserStandard" in my Feed.
In Visual Studio, Manage NuGetPackages, my NuGet does not have any dependencies.

My NuGet SDK: .NET Standard 2.0 (note: compatible with imported projects since it works if I manually add TextFieldParserStandard).

If needed I can give the yaml pipeline. This targets somehow the problem. [Build NuGet Package automatically including referenced dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173568/build-nuget-package-automatically-including-referenced-dependencies)

But adding `IncludeReferencedProjects` to yaml did not solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure custom Nuget package external libraries

That because you are not add the reference package `TextFieldParserStandard` to your custom package `MyNuGet` as dependency.

In this case, it will not automatically install the reference package `TextFieldParserStandard` to your project when you install the package `MyNuGet`.

To resolve this issue, you could add the property `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` for the package `TextFieldParserStandard` in your project `MyNuGet` file `MyNuGet.csproj`:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="TextFieldParserStandard" Version="1.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Submit this change to the repo, then generate the new package for your custom package, it will have the `TextFieldParserStandard` package as dependecy:

[image]

**Update:**

Since `TextFieldParser` cannot be referenced in unit tests.

You could try to create your `.nupsec` file with `Dependencies` element, like:

```
<dependencies>             
  <dependency id="another-package" version="3.0.0" />             
  <dependency id="yet-another-package" version="1.0.0" />        
</dependencies>
```

You can refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#example-nuspec-files) for some more details.

Comment: After that action, my unit tests in MyNuget no longer run because the error `Could not load file or assembly`. TextFieldParser cannot be referenced in unit tests. In Build solution the pipeline also fails. It seems PrivateAssets is doing the opposite and telling that the package is development-only.

Comment: @MihaiSocaciu, Got it. Since TextFieldParser cannot be referenced in unit tests. You could try to create your `.nupsec` file with Dependencies element, like:         
      `<dependencies>
            <dependency id="another-package" version="3.0.0" />
            <dependency id="yet-another-package" version="1.0.0" />
       `</dependencies>  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#example-nuspec-files

Comment: Dependency now appears, but 
`MyNuGet 1.0.0 does not support any target frameworks`
`MyNuGet 1.0.0  is not compatible with uap10.0.16299`
. I tried this in .nuspec, but its of no help:
```  
<files>
  <file src="**\MyNuget.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.0\MyNuget.dll" />  
</files>
```
I need to use the package in a UWP app and a .NET Core 3.1 app. I checked compatibility chart and even before it was working. It only seems the .nuspec is missing something.

Comment: The .nuspec file solves the problem of dependency. If you edit your answer I can mark it as the solution and I will create another question about Target framework comaptibility. It seems MyNuget cannot be used, not even in .Net Standard 2.0 projects. The same SDK as the library.

Comment: @MihaiSocaciu, I have updated the answer. Welcome to post another question.

Comment: Update: this solution solved all the previous problems above 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60618939/9442199